# Is there a way to change delimiters of documentation string in Common Lisp?

Tags: documentation, common-lisp

I sometimes put examples of function calls and their output in the documentation string of a function definition.

```
(defun js-[] (&rest args)
  "Javascript array literal statement.
  (js-[] 1 2 3)
  > \"[1, 2, 3]\"
  "
  (format nil "[~{~A~^, ~}]" (mapcar #'js-expr args)))
```

But sometimes the output of the function is a string. So I have to escape the double quotes in the example output. This becomes tedious very quickly.

**Is there a way to change the docstring delimiter from double quotes to something else so I don't have to keep escaping them?**

Please note that sometimes it's worse than just escaping once:

```
(defun js-~ (str)
  "Javascript string statement. This is needed so that double quotes are inserted.
  (js-~ \"string\")
  > \"\\\"string\\\"\"
  "
  (format nil "\"~A\"" str))
```

Here there is an additional problem. Reading the docstring is difficult.

Comment: Notice that editors such as Emacs with paredit can handle the escaping for you. Paredit should automatically escape double quotes when you enter them unless the cursor is at the end of the string. You can also use `M-"` to add double quotes around the region, escaping any double quotes or backslashes in it.

Comment: Yes, true. However, the second example above remains a problem. The docstring is difficult to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a reader macro that slurps in a multi line string like this:

```
(defun hash-slash-reader (stream slash arg)
  (declare (ignore slash arg))
  (loop :with s := (make-string-output-stream)
        :for c := (read-char stream)
        :if (and (eql #\/ c) (eql #\# (peek-char nil stream)))
             :do (read-char stream) (return (get-output-stream-string s))
        :if (eql #\Newline c)
             :do (peek-char t stream)
        :do (princ c s)))

(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\/ #'hash-slash-reader)
```

Now you can do:

```
(defun js-~ (str)
  #/ --------------------------
  Javascript string statement. 
  This is needed so that double quotes are inserted.

  (js-~ "string")
  > "\"string\""      
  -------------------------- /#
  (format nil "\"~A\"" str))
```

The documentation string will be added just as if you'd written it with double quotes. **This is effectively the same as changing the delimiter for strings!**. In fact, it is an ***additional*** way to delimit strings.

Which is why you can use it (not recommended though) in regular lisp code, and not just for documentation purposes.

Using `/` as the sub-character of the dispatch macro, helps keep it conceptually close to the multiline comment, but avoids being ignored by the reader altogether.

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

***Yes***, you can, ***no***, you do not want to do it.

## No, CL has just one syntax for strings

The only way to represent a string in Common Lisp is to use
[Double-Quote `"`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_de.htm).

## Yes, you can modify the reader so that something else denotes a string

E.g., suppose you want to a string to be started and stopped by, say, `@`.
(This is an ordinary character rarely used in symbol names,
in contrast to `%` and `$` which are often used in implementation-internal symbols.)

Set the properties of `@` from `"`:

```
(multiple-value-bind (function non-terminating-p)
    (get-macro-character #\")
  (set-macro-character #\@ function non-terminating-p))
```

Now:

```
(read-from-string "@123@")
==>  "123" ; 5
(read-from-string @"123"@)
==> "123" ; 5
```

Do not forget to [restore the input syntax to standard Common Lisp syntax](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_rdt.htm):

```
(setq *readtable* (copy-readtable nil))
```

See [Reader](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/23_.htm).

## You might be able to modify the printer

The standard does not require that the printing of standard objects
(such as a [`string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_string.htm)) to be
used-modifiable.

You can *try* defining a [`print-object`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pr_obj.htm) method:

```
(defmethod print-object ((o string) (d stream))
  ...)
```

however,

- implementing this correctly is **not** easy
- this is [non-conforming code](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/01_eb.htm) ([defining a method for a standardized generic function which is applicable when all of the arguments are direct instances of standardized classes](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_abab.htm))
- thus many implementations will signal errors on this code,
- even if you disable [package locks](http://clisp.org/impnotes/pack-lock.html) &c, the implementation is free to ignore your method.

## No, you do not want to do that

The code exists for people to read it.

Changing Lisp syntax will make it harder for others to read your code.

It will also confuse various tools you use (editor &c).

CL has many warts, but this is not one of them ;-)

PS. See also [`documentation`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm) and [`describe`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_descri.htm), as well as comment syntax [Sharpsign Vertical-Bar](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhs.htm) and [Semicolon](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dd.htm).

Comment: I considered messing with the readtable, but it still wouldn't work, because the output of any example will in that case be delimited by the new delimiter, and then I would have to escape that anyway. So back to square one. No?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea. Write your docstrings as usual, without examples.

```
(defun js-~ (str)
  "Javascript array literal statement."
  ...)
```

Define tests. That can be as simple as:

```
(defparameter *tests*
  '(((js-~ "string") . "\"string\"")
     ...))
```

Use that list to perform tests:

```
(loop for (form . expected) in *tests*
      for (fn . args) = form
      for actual = (apply fn args)
      do (assert (equalp actual expected)))
```

... and to update the documentation. Be careful, this appends to the existing documentation string, so don't run it twice.

```
(loop for (form . expected) in *tests*
      for (fn . args) = form
      do (setf (documentation fn 'function)
               (format nil
                       "~a~%~%    ~S~%    => ~S"
                       (documentation fn 'function)
                       form
                       expected)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can (ab)use [cl-interpol](http://weitz.de/cl-interpol/). Although the purpose of the library is to enable string interpolation it also allows custom string delimiters, if you don't mind preprending the string with `#?`. e.j.

```
CL-USER> (cl-interpol:enable-interpol-syntax)
; No values
CL-USER> #?'foo'
"foo"
CL-USER> #?/foo/
"foo"
CL-USER> #?{foo}
"foo"
CL-USER>
```

so after enabling the interpol reader macro you could write

```
(defun js-[] (&rest args)
  #?'Javascript array literal statement.
  (js-[] 1 2 3)
  > "[1, 2, 3]"
  '
```